# Removing files in GIT

Tags: git

How do I remove files in the remote repository?

Comment: Do you want to remove files from your project for the future or do you want to remove files from previous commits because they contain passwords or some similar reason?

Comment: git rm path and then commit-push does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove file from repository and filesystem

```
git rm my_path/my_file
```

Force removing file

```
git rm --force my_path/my_file
```

Remove file only from your repository not in your file system

```
git rm --cached my_path/my_file
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it in Git GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this `git filter-branch` command to rewrite remote origin branch. So that delete those files you wanna clean in all commits.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch